# Finding all id's with wildcards

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page with multiple `tr` tags with an id that starts with `news`.

The id's are named:

```
news1

news2
```

`news3` ... etc.

As the amount of ids with the suffic of news changes. I'd like my code to be flexible. So being able to search with a wildcard would be great.

How would I go about coding this?

```
newsItems = soupified_page.find_all('tr', id='news')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get all `tr`s and check their ids :

```
newsItems = [item for item in soupified_page.find_all('tr') if item['id'].startswith('news')]
```